# OFDM IDFT implementation....

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, sampling, fast-fourier-transform, discrete-time

i have some doubts with the implementation of the IDFT in OFDM systems.
The question concerns the expression of the IDFT of the OFDM signal.
During the symbols period $T_s$ we have the following base-band OFDM signal:
$$x(t)=\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}X_m e^{j2 \pi \frac{m}{T_s} t},\ \ \  0\leq t \leq T_s$$
If we sample the signal at time instants $t = k\,Ts/N$, we have:
$$x_k=x \left(k \frac{T_s}{N}\right) =\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}X_m e^{j\frac{2 \pi  }{N}m\,k}\ \ \ \ \text{with }k=0,1,\dotso,N-1$$
Now, except for a multiplying constant ($1/N$), the above
formula is the equation of an N-point inverse discrete Fourier transform (IDFT).

In the OFDM Transmitter and Receiver we implement the respectively the IDFT and DFT to convert the symbol $\{X_0,X_1,\dotso,X_{N-1}\}$ to the time domain symbol sequence $\{x_0,x_1,\dotso,x_{N-1}\}$ and viceversa.

What I was wondering is if the $1/N$ factor that is absent in the previous expression of the IDFT that I have reported is due only to a convention of normalization of the power of the transmitted signal. Furthermore, is the absence of this factor an error?

Comment: Explanation for acronym OFDM ? Nobody is supposed to know the $26^4$ acronyms with 4 letters... Though familiar with FFT, I had never met this one...

Comment: It means Ortoganl Frequency Division Multiplexing, is the transmission technique used in the modern wireless comunication system.

Comment: If you always work with the same $N$, neglecting the front factor $N$ or $1/N$ is very frequent (no pun intended) and has no impact. It can be harmfull if you change $N \to 2N$ for example. If you consider publishing, you have to keep it...